# Calculate the formula of RC low pass filter

Tags: filter, transfer-function, low-pass

In RC filter, the low pass filter formula is

$$H(s) = \frac{V_\text{o}(s)}{V_\text{in}(s)} = \frac{1}{RCs + 1}$$
$$H(j\omega) = \frac{1}{j\omega RC + 1}$$

and the absolute value is

$$|H(j\omega)| = \frac{\frac{1}{RC}}{\sqrt{\omega^2 + \left(\frac{1}{RC}\right)^2}}$$
$$\theta(j\omega) = -\tan^{-1}(\omega RC)$$

To make as the absolute value, do I need to square each part (real part and imaginary part) individually and then take the square root of it together?

Comment: That's a general math question, how to take absolute value of a complex number. It does not otherwise relate to low pass filters or electronics. It might be faster to look up how complex numbers work on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

### One approach

\$\left.\middle| H \middle|\right.=\left.\left.\sqrt{ H\cdot H^* }\right.\right.\$, where \$H^*\$ is the complex conjugate of \$H\$.

If \$H=\frac{N}{D}\$, where \$N=a_1+j\,a_2\$ and \$D=b_1+j\,b_2\$ (and therefore \$N^*=a_1-j\,a_2\$ and \$D^*=b_1-j\,b_2\$), then \$\left.\middle| H \middle|\right.=\left.\middle| \frac{N}{D} \middle|\right.=\frac{\left.\middle| N \middle|\right.}{\left.\middle| D \middle|\right.}=\frac{\left.\left.\sqrt{ N\,\cdot\, N^* }\right.\right.}{\left.\left.\sqrt{ D\,\cdot\, D^* }\right.\right.}=\frac{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}}{\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}}\$.

If \$H=\left. \frac{1}{j\omega R C+1} \right.\$ then \$\left.\middle| H \middle|\right.=\left.\middle| \frac{1}{j\omega R C+1} \middle|\right.=\frac1{\sqrt{\left(j\omega R C+1\right)\cdot\left(-j\omega R C+1\right)}}=\frac1{\sqrt{R^2C^2\omega^2+1}}\cdot\frac{\frac1{RC}}{\frac1{RC}}=
\frac{\frac1{RC}}{\sqrt{\omega^2+\frac1{R^2C^2}}}\$

### Another approach using Euler's

For both phase and magnitude for complex values like the above, it's perhaps a little easier (if you know about Euler's, anyway) is to set \$r_a=\left.\middle| N \middle|\right.=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}\$, \$r_b=\left.\middle| D \middle|\right.=\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}\$, \$\phi_a=\arg\left(N\right)\$, and \$\phi_b=\arg\left(D\right)\$ and then to recast \$N\$ and \$D\$ as \$N=r_a\cdot\exp\left(j\,\phi_a\right)\$ and \$D=r_b\cdot\exp\left(j\,\phi_a\right)\$. Now, everything just kind of falls out so that \$H=\frac{r_a\,\cdot\,\exp\left(j\,\phi_a\right)}{r_b\,\cdot\,\exp\left(j\,\phi_b\right)}=\frac{r_a}{r_b}\exp\left(j\left[\phi_a-\phi_b\right]\right)\$.

The magnitude is just \$\frac{r_a}{r_b}\$ and you can just read that straight off from the result. The phase is similarly easy to read as \$\phi_a-\phi_b\$, also just read off directly.

That's one of the nice things about Euler's in this context. It's easier to see ***why*** the magnitude is the way it is and how to get the right value for the phase, too.